# Android change circle color and textColor of radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

When I click on Radio Button, I want the *color of the text and the color of the circle* to change ***at the same time as*** in the image below.

[image]

***NOTE***

The color of choice for the circle and text is none of the colors of the colorPrimary or colorAccent.

Comment: Hi Abolfazl, when you click color of button will change, so you want to change color of text, yes?

Comment: I want both to change when clicked

Comment: I have your answer first, then I checked this And that I explained in the text I want to be at the same time

Comment: And you can check the answer, if it was wrong to mention in the comment, it was right for me @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Your image in question and image in correct answer aren't the same, it's strange that somebody from your company understands the question very well meanwhile question needs more clearity

Comment: The question was clear to me. @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the text and color of the circles at the same time, follow these steps

1.add style below

```
<style name="radioButton" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#0f0</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#f00</item>
  </style>
```

2.add this selector.xml to drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#0f0" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:color="#f00" android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:color="#0f0" />
</selector>
```

3.add selector and style to RadioButton

```
 <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="select"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:theme="@style/radioButton"
            app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" />
```

FULL CODE:

```
<RadioGroup
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:checkedButton="@+id/one"
          android:layoutDirection="ltr"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="select"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:theme="@style/radioButton"
            app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" />

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="not select"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:theme="@style/radioButton"
            app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

*And Result*

[image]

**Note:** I used Google Material

Answer (score 0):

```
radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if(radiobutton.isChecked())
        {
            // Changing radio button 1 color on checked.
            radiobutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"))}}
```

Comment: That's right, but there are ways to do this without coding.

Comment: Where do you specify that you want to change color with code or in XML?! @abolfazlbazghandi

Comment: I said right, I didn't say there was a problem, and I said there are other ways without coding. This is a problem!

Answer (score -1):

The `MaterialRadioButton` uses as default a selector where the colors are based on `colorOnSurface` when `unchecked` and `colorControlActivated` when `checked` defined in your app theme.

You can override them using a `android:theme` attribute.
Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.RadioButton"/>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.RadioButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/.....</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/.....</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

You can also set the `useMaterialThemeColors` attribute to `false`

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    ...
    useMaterialThemeColors="false"/>
```

and apply a custom selector using `CompoundButtonCompat#setButtonTintList`.

with a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="..." android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"  />
  <item android:color="..." android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" />
  <item android:color="..." android:state_enabled="false" android:state_checked="true"  />
  <item android:color="..." android:state_enabled="false" android:state_checked="false" />  
</selector>
```